# Software for creating and maintaining a vector icon set

Tags: windows, osx, vector-graphics, svg, icon

I use InkScape (both Windows and OS X) for creating vector-based flat icons, but the process is really painful: opening the icons files one-by-one, exporting them one-by-one to png, there is not a "gallery" option for easy picking and categorization, etc, etc. It is obvious that InkScape was not created for that purpose.

I want to know if there is a better alternative (free or paid), for maintaining a whole icon set, with strong emphasis in vector tools and some facility for pixel-perfect editing.

Answer (score 1):

Found my own answer.

Affinity Designer for OS X seems to have all the features needed: Can draw several vectorial icons in a single page and declare many export zones for exporting icons individually (or in batch).

It is overloaded with tons of vector and raster features.